# Fill multiple SELECT with one array

Tags: arrays, select, fill

I am having trouble with something I think is strange. Atleast I don't know why is happening.

I got a function that returns an array with People's information. Something like this:

```
$people= controllerGetAllPeople();
```

Then I am using this array and a foreach to fill some SELECTS:

```
<select name="owner">
      <?php
      foreach($people as $person) {
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $person["code"]; ?>"><?php echo $person["name"]." ".$person["lastname"]; ?></option>
           <?php
      }
       ?>
 </select>
```

And I have to fill exactly the same box 3 times more because the app asks you to select the Owner, the Intermediate, the Buyer, etc etc... and the same list of people must appear. But what happens is that when I use later the same code above (I am not using $people= controllerGetAllPeople(); again) the SELECTS are not being filled.

What do you think is the cause? Am I forgeting to do something?

Thank you beforehand!

EDIT:

if I use again the $people= controllerGetAllPeople(); it would look like

```
$people= controllerGetAllPeople();

<select name="owner">
      <?php
      foreach($people as $person) {
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $person["code"]; ?>"><?php echo $person["name"]." ".$person["lastname"]; ?></option>
           <?php
      }
       ?>
 </select>

$people= controllerGetAllPeople();

<select name="intermediate">
      <?php
      foreach($people as $person) {
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $person["code"]; ?>"><?php echo $person["name"]." ".$person["lastname"]; ?></option>
           <?php
      }
       ?>
 </select>

$people= controllerGetAllPeople();

<select name="buyer">
      <?php
      foreach($people as $person) {
           ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $person["code"]; ?>"><?php echo $person["name"]." ".$person["lastname"]; ?></option>
           <?php
      }
       ?>
 </select>
```

ISN'T it an ugly way to do it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not re-using the $people=controllerGetAllPeople(); ?

Comment: @jeff Well, because why should I tell the controller again to generate exactly the same array? Why can't I reuse the same array? I don't understand.

I edited the question so you get what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Sorry I misread your statement. While the manual states you shouldn't need to do this but you might want to add reset($people); before re-using the array. If that doesn't work then there is probably something else going on.

Comment: @jeff Is not working... I am using reset($people) before every foreach statement. And the only SELECT that is being filled is the first one! weird!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$people= controllerGetAllPeople();

<select name="intermediate">
      <?php
      foreach($people as $person) {
```

TO

```
// $people= controllerGetAllPeople();
<select name="intermediate">
      <?php
      reset( $people );
      foreach($people as $person) {
```

Comment: That's exacly what I am doing. I can't believe it's not working :/